# cannot access nusoap webservice on my hosted website to localhost, but work on localhost to localhost

Tags: php, web-services

I didn't know what is wrong with my server. It looks like can't access local nusoap webservice ..
but working fine when my web still on localhost.
When I hosted it, it can't access ws nusoap .
I even disable firewall on my PC, but still it didn't work
.
here my code

```
public function index() {
$this->load->helper('url');
     $this->load->library("Nusoap_lib");

        $url = 'http://localhost:8082/ws/live.php?wsdl';

        $client = new nusoap_client($url, true);
        echo $url;
        $proxy = $client->getproxy();


        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $result=$proxy->GetToken($username, $password);
        $token = $result;
        $var = 2011;
        $tahun = (int)$var;
        $table = 'nilai';
        $filter = "id_smt = 20141";
        //$filter = "";
        $order = "";
        $jumlah = $proxy->GetCountRecordset($token, $table, $filter);
```

I got error like this

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function GetToken() on null

Filename: /var/www/validator-feeder/application/controllers/Wsa.php

Line Number: 19
```

The point is my hosted website cannot access localhost

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8082/ws/live.php?wsdl';
```

but my local website can access localhost.

any idea what cause this ??

Comment: why are you going through the web server and not calling the file locally? "localhost" on a webserver makes no sense

Comment: my website has function to access webservice both on localhost and hosted web. But can't access to localhost

Comment: no external site can access "localhost" which is fact not local, as its another network

Comment: so what should I do now ?? maybe change localhost to PC's IP Address ??

Comment: yes, if your pc has a static a address, is always on, and has a web-server, and appropriate firewall rule, and your crazy enough to allow the outside world to access your computer.

Comment: it doesn't have static address. I'm trying use with local address from my router like 192.168.1.6 , doesn't work either.

Comment: just dont. host it. its cheap or even free, dont let the outside world any where near your pc. 192... is an internal address never accessible to the outside world